# How to execute a php header script from javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have the following script `validation.php`

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['userId'])){
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: home.php');
    exit;    
}
?>
```

I would like to execute this script every time someone clicks a button in the `#main-display`

```
$("#main-display").on('click', 'button', function (event){
    //some code in here
});
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: $("#main-display").on('click', 'button', function (event){ 
jQuery.ajax('your.domain.tld/path/validation.php');}); - that's all.

Comment: You will also need to remove `header('Location: home.php');` and instead put similar to `echo "redirect";`... in the js you will have Akhil Thayyil's answer replacing `alert("response is "+data);` with `if(data=="redirect"){ window.location.href="home.php"; }`

Comment: Thanks ricky, you hit the nail on the head, I'll try this out now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant do a redirect from within a ajax request directly since it will only redirect the response page to home.php and not the current main DOM window.

You are going to have to modify it to something like this in the php:

```
   if(!isset($_SESSION['userId'])){
       session_destroy();
       $response['status'] = 'false';
   }
   else {
       $response['status'] = 'true';
   }
   echo json_encode($response);
```

And then on the javascript

```
$("#main-display").on('click', 'button', function (event){
     $.getJSON('/path/to/loginStatus.php', {}, function(response) {
          if(response.status == 'false') {
               location.href = 'home.php';
           }
     });    
});
```

Comment: Thanks Manatok, you need to specify the datatype as json, otherwise it `response.status` is `undefined`

Comment: ah yes, I have made the change.

Answer (score 1):

To start from the simplest, `$.get('validation.php')` is enough to get your script to run, but to do something useful with it you 'll need to provide more context. For the most generic "do-everything" method with bazillions of options, see [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/); everything else is a subset of this¹.

¹ *This is not strictly true, but there are only a couple of minor exceptions that you shouldn't care about at this point*.

Answer (score -1):

Try this ..

```
  $("#main-display").on('click', 'button', function (event){
       $.get("validate.php",function(data){
    alert("response is "+data);

       });
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#main-display').click(function(){
 $.get('validate.php');
});
```

Hope this works!